# Custom Validation in Spring MVC 3.0 - Pass @Model to Validator

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to write a custom validator in a Spring MVC application. I would like to know if there a way to pass the @Model object to a custom spring validator?

Say, I have a Person object and Account object. I have to write a custom validator to validate Person, but the validation is dependent of the Account object and other objects in session.

For example, Person cannot have more than 3 accounts, account types have to be of specific category and not old than 3 years (this value, ie the number years is dynamic based on the profile logged in and  is in session).

How can I pass both objects, especially @Model to the validator.

```
public class ServiceValidator implements Validator {

@Autowired
private ServiceDAO servicesDao;

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clasz) {
    return clasz.isAssignableFrom(Person.class);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
     Person subscriber = (Person) obj;
    // How can I access @Model object here ???

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubt if you can but have two workarounds:

**a.** If it is persisted data that you are looking for, probably it is just better to retrieve it once more in the validator and validate using that data, so for eg, in your case if you are validating person and persons account details are retrievable from DB, then get it from DB and validate in your validator using the retrieved data.

**b.** Probably this is a better approach if the number of places where you need to use the validator is fairly confined:

```
public class ServiceValidator {

@Autowired
private ServiceDAO servicesDao;

public void validate(Person subscriber, List<Account> accounts, ..., Errors errors) {


}
```

Just call the above validator directly from your requestmapped methods..

In your controller..

```
List<Account> accounts = //retrieve from session
serviceValidator.validate(subscriber, accounts, ...errors);
if (errors.hasErrors())..
else..
```

Comment: Thanks Biju. I did not think I can write my own validate() method. I was wondering how to pass the List<Account> as the validate method signature did not support it....`public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
` OK, if I take this approach, do I have to invoke the validator manually (`ServiceValidator s = new ServiceValidator()`)

Comment: I have two pages in my app. One page to collect Person info (which is validated using annotations) and another page, where we can add accounts to a Person. I do not want the custom validator to fire when I submit my first page, but I need it in the second page. I only have one controller. If I bind my ServiceValidator to my only controller, will that be invoked even when I submit the first page. Thanks.

Comment: You can wire the ServiceValidator into your controller instead of instantiating it, regarding when to fire it, since it is completely under your control(as you are now calling the validate explicitly), you can selectively choose to fire it at the appropriate points in your code

Comment: Thanks. I will try to overloaded validate method and see if it solves my issue.